# Trigger a Azure Pipeline in ProjectB from a pipeline in ProjectA

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to initiate a pipeline from another pipeline in Azure DevOps. While I've come across documentation on resource triggers, my challenge is that I don't want the pipeline that is being triggered (let's call it Pipeline B) to be the one modified to include the trigger. Instead, I want the trigger configuration to be in the pipeline for Project A (Pipeline A). In other words, I want to control the trigger from Pipeline A without altering the YAML configuration of Pipeline B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have below resources within the same Azure DevOps organization:

- YAML file of **PipelineA** is in **RepositoryA**, and **RepositoryA** is in **ProjectA**.
- YAML file of **PipelineB** is in **RepositoryB**, and **RepositoryB** is in **ProjectB**.

If you want **PipelineB** can only be triggered by **PipelineA**, in the YAML file of **PipelineB**, you can set the triggers and pipeline resources like as below.

```yaml
# Disable CI triggers from RepositoryB.
trigger: none

# Set pipeline resource.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipeA  # This a custom alias of the pipeline resource. You can set it as other if you like.
    project: {actual name of ProjectA}
    source: {actual name of PipelineA}
    trigger: true

. . .
```

With above configurations:

- **`trigger: none`**: Disable CI triggers. Any changes in **RepositoryB** will not automatically trigger **PipelineB**.
- **`trigger: true`** under pipeline resource: Every run of **PipelineA** is successfully completed, a run of **PipelineB** will be triggered.

---

If you want **PipelineB** can be triggered only when **PipelineA** is triggered for particular branches or tags, you can set branches filter or tags filter under pipeline resource.

For example:

```yaml
trigger: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipeA
    project: {name of ProjectA}
    source: {name of PipelineA}
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
```

With above configuration, if a run of **PipelineA** is triggered for **`main`** branch in **RepositoryA**, after the run is successfully completed, a run of **PipelineB** will be triggered. Otherwise, the **PipelineB** will not be triggered.

For more details, reference below documentations:

- [**Pipeline completion triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops)
- [**resources.pipelines.pipeline definition**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines)
- [**CI triggers in Azure Repos Git**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#disabling-the-ci-trigger)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want **PipelineA** can trigger **PipelineB** without setting pipeline resource in the YAML file of **PipelineB**, in **PipelineA**, you can set up a step to call the REST API "[**Runs - Run Pipeline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)" (or the Azure CLI "[**az pipelines run**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-run)") to trigger a run of **PipelineB**.

In this situation, **PipelineA** will not be considered as the pipeline resource of **PipelineB**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my questions was if it is possible to have this scenario without the need to modify PipelineB. In your solution I would need to specify in PipelineB the resource PipelineA. But my questions is whteter it is possible to trigger PipelineB by specifiying it only in PipelineA.

Comment: @mr_bean, The triggers set in a pipeline is only available for current pipeline. For you demands, I have updated my above answer with a workaround. Check and try it.